# Symbol substitution in URLs: What to do when replacement already exists in input?

Tags: url, url-rewriting, substitution

*If you can come up with a better title, feel free to edit.*

I am trying to create a simple JavaScript system that shows a certain comic based on the #fragment identifier (a.k.a. hash) of the URL.

When using spaces or similar special characters in this hash they will get converted to %20 or a similar sequence, through means of URL encoding.

This does not look nice. Thus, when you want to refer to a certain comic,blogpost,etc by its title in the URL, I believe it is common to replace all spaces and other URL-unsafe characters by a different URL-safe symbol. In fact, StackOverflow does this as well.

However, what do I do when the symbol I want to replace it with also exists in the input string?

For instance, when I substitute all spaces ( ) with hyphens (-), what do I do with already existing hyphens?

Comment: Why would you want to "decode" it? Do you use the URL to create the page title?

Comment: I am using the fragment identifier part of the URL to find out what exact page to load. I am trying to implement a webcomic structure, but without any server-side scripting. Thus the URL indicates what exact comic to load. And if there's no comic with that name or there's no hash set, load the newest one.

Comment: Ah, I see. I think you should add this to your question, as this is kind of a special case.

Comment: I have now rewarded the bounty to the question that has the most literal answer. It's too bad that I can not split the bounty, because Stephen McDaniel's answer is great as well. Thanks a lot for your input!

Answer (score 2):

An alternate solution would be to implement it in way similar to Stack Overflow.  Include **both** an internal identifier and a 'user friendly' identifier in the URL.  For example, this is the 'standard' link to this question:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543452/symbol-substitution-in-urls-what-to-do-when-replacement-already-exists-in-input
```

But the following link works just as well:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14543452/this-part-of-the-address-is-just-to-look-nice
```

You could do something similar to include some sort of identifier (perhaps a sequential number) for each comic and the user-friendly name such as: example.com/comics/#42-the-forty-second-comic-title.

There are a number of benefits to this system:

- It is very easy to implement - just parse the portion of the fragment before the first dash (-) and use that to build the URL to the specific comic
- It allows you to provide a [permanent link](http://codex.wordpress.org/Introduction_to_Blogging#Pretty_Permalinks) to the comic since the internal identifier part would never change even if you happened to change the comic's title
- It allows you to easily rename comics without worrying about updating URLs, image paths, etc. since the comic name is not strictly necessary for the system to work correctly
- It makes Next and Previous buttons easy to implement using only client-side JavaScript (since you know the comic before '#23-some-title' is going to be '#23'

Answer (score 1):

This is a general problem, and the solution is called [Character Escaping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character). The basic approach goes as follows:

1. Pick a character that is to be known as the 'Escape character'. In C/C++/Java/etc, it's the backslash (\). In URLs, it's the percent sign (%). Yours could be anything you want.
2. After the escape, you're get to define an alternate character set and rules. In C/C++/Java/etc, for example,  \n means new line while \0 is the null character. In a URL, the % is followed by two hexadecimal characters.
3. **CRITICAL**: Ensure that the escape sequence includes a way for specifying the escape character itself. In C/C++/Java, \\ means \. In URL encoding, it's %25.

May I propose, for your problem, that you pick the -, # or @ (but any legal untransformed URL encoded character is fine). Let's assume you use -, then the following would work:

1. -- is -
2. -= could be a space

(Remember that you make the rules according to the meta-rules above. Anything goes.)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the schema used by Wikipedia to basically generate an id from the post title, which has the advantage that it also conveys information about the post, compared to a plain hash tag. It should be fairly simple to write a [transducer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_state_transducer) that takes input that looks like `Some article` and outputs `Some_Article`, but you must make sure that you generate unique ids. For example, for the keyword `Machine` Wikipedia would provide a disambiguation page at [http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_(disambiguation)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_%28disambiguation%29).